# PHP action when all other instances have terminated

Tags: php

In my automatic updater I request updates from a database with a PHP script in my Centos 7 server.

However when I need to push an update, I call the PHP script in a way that next calls for update are ignored until I finish pushing.

My problem is to wait until existing calls for update to the PHP finish before I start pushing.

- Put a variable inside the database, increment on call, decrement on finish? What if the script dies for any reason, my pushing script will remain locked.
- Same with a file with `flock()`.
- Should I use some Centos related feature to lock memory with a mutex? In Windows, I would use a std::recursive_mutex to lock for writing.

Is there a proper suggested way to do it?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Locks are automatically removed if the locking process dies.

Comment: So, LOCK_SH for all updaters, and LOCK_EX for my pusher?

Comment: That sounds right